# Clip line network shapefile in R using raster

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, geotiff

I am quite new to R, so please bear with me :)

I currently use R to clip a fuel raster ("fuel_lcdb3_100m.tif") and elevation raster("elevation_100m.tif") to a smaller extent based on what coordinates I put in.

Below are all the commands I have pasted into R. The first two lines were obviously only done on install, so I start on line 3 when I am clipping.

The X and Y coordinates change based on the centre point I want to use. The buffer is always 50, and the fileprefix is the name of the area I'm working on.

```
install.packages(pkgs=c("raster", "rgdal", "sp"))

install.packages(pkgs="fgm.tools_0.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")

library("fgm.tools") 

fgm.clip 

setwd("D:/Users/Me/Documents/R/Geotiff") 

fgm.clip(fuel="fuel_lcdb3_100m.tif", elv=" elevation_100m.tif", lon.x=*170.18502*, lat.y=*-
    43.901942*, buffer=50, fileprefix="mount_cook")
```

After pressing ENTER, this provides me with 4 outputs I need:

- "mount_cook_elevation.asc"
- "mount_cook_elevation.prj"
- "mount_cook_fuel.asc"
- "mount_cook_fuel.prj"

**Following this output, I would also like to use R to clip a road network shapefile (lines, not polygons), to the same extent of the rasters from above.

Could someone please let me know if this is possible and how I would go about it? Again, I am quite new to R so will need clear instructions please :)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can do both operations with raster::crop